# How can I find the SQL queries that are creating temporary tables on disk?

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, mysqltuner

I got a job maintaining a high traffic webapp that uses MySQL. I'm using MySQLTuner, a Perl script that makes recommendations to improve MySQL performance. Recently I've been getting the following error from MySQLTuner:

```
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 49% (50M on disk / 102M total)
```

How can I find out which queries are creating temporary tables on disk?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#TRACING

Comment: Not for nothing, but tables that do not vaporize or at least auto-purge their data when their session closes are hard pressed to be called temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Search your perl code for `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.  For searching stored procs and stuff on the backend (if you're using TOAD) you can do `Tools->Object Search` then search for that same string.  Or dump the DB and search the dump text file for that string.